# vue js return empty object response

Tags: vue.js

Axios 'get' request returns an empty object response when I pass the route to retrieve JSON object

I want to retrieve JSON data from my registration controller but gets an empty response

this is my registration controller

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $registration =
         $this->registrationRepository->findRegistrationById($id);

    return response()->json($registration);
}
```

this is my script

```js
 export default {
   props:{
      studentid:Number,
      registrationid:Number,
   },
   data(){
     return {
       registration:{}
     }
   },
   created(){
     this.loadRegisteredSubjects();
   },
   methods: {
     loadRegisteredSubjects(){
       axios.get('/admin/registrations/'+this.registrationid+'/show')
         .then(response => (this.registration = response)
     }
   }

 }
```

when I passed the route from where to retrieve the data

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/registrations/13/show

i get the desire results which is

```
{"id":13,"student_id":2,"subjects":"3,4,5","created_at":"2019-10-01 01:13:13","updated_at":"2019-10-01 01:13:13"}
```

unfortunately, I get an empty registration object when I pass the same route to Axios

Comment: In your browser's network panel, do you see a response? What's the HTTP code for that response?

Comment: yes, this is the response  {"id":12,"student_id":1,"subjects":"1,2,3","created_at":"2019-10-01 00:29:33","updated_at":"2019-10-01 00:29:33"}

Comment: You are not using `reponse`, if so this `response.data` would error. Can you update the question with the actual code you are using?

Comment: Your latest edit still has a typo that will cause a syntax error. As I said below in another comment, you want `.then(response => { this.registration = response.data })`

Answer (score 2):

If the code you've shared is your actual code, I think you may just have a typo.

```
reponse => (this.registration = response.data)
```

`reponse` != `response`

Comment: yes i have fix it but still get empty registration object even though i get a response in my browsers network panel

Comment: Time to start `console.log`ging out things like `response.data` to make sure they contain what you think they contain, then.

Comment: ({response}) => (this.registration = response.data)

Comment: i got  Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: I must admit to not being fully comfortable with arrow functions. Does `axios.get('/admin/registrations/'+this.registrationid+'/show').then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});` work?

Comment: how should i pass the response to registration to retrieve the data

Comment: One step at a time. Does what I suggested work? Do you get the response in the console?

Comment: @eons please update the code in your question if it's still not working. You want `.then(response => { this.registration = response.data })`